# How can I compute this:$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(2x)^2 \cosh x} {1+\cosh 2x} dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

How can I solve this integral? $$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(2x)^2 \cosh x} {1+\cosh 2x} dx$$ I get this: $I=I_1+I_2$ and $I_1=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln 2}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx=\pi/2$ and $I_2=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{e^x+e^{-2x}}dx$ and I can't solve $I_2$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You’re neglecting the square of the logarithm, and your evaluation of $I_1$ is wrong

Comment: Did you mean $(\ln 2x)^2$ or $\ln((2x)^2)$?

Comment: Is $I_2$'s integrand's denominator definitely meant to be $e^x+e^{-\color{red}{2}x}$?

Comment: yeah its:$\int_0^\infty\frac{2ln2xcoshx}{cosh^2x}dx= \int_0^\infty\frac{ln2x}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx= \int_0^\infty\frac {ln2}{e^x+e^{-x}}dx +\frac {lnxe^{-x}}{1+e^{-2x}}dx $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}\cosh x}{1+\cosh2x}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx}{1+e^{-2x}}=\Gamma(s)\beta(s),$$with $\beta$ the [Dirichlet beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function#Definition), so$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{s-1}\ln^nx\cosh x}{1+\cosh2x}dx=\frac{d^n}{ds^n}(\Gamma(s)\beta(s)).$$You need to evaluate the cases $n=0$ and $n=1$ (and also the case $n=2$, if $\ln(2x)^2$ meant $(\ln(2x))^2$) at $s=1$. You'll find $\beta(1),\,\beta^\prime(1)$ [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function#Special_values). But if anyone knows $\beta^{\prime\prime}(1)$, [they've got *Wolfram Alpha* beat](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=second+derivative+of+dirichlet+beta+function+at+1&dataset=).

Answer (score 2):

*After @J.G.'s answer*
$$\beta(1)=\frac \pi 4$$
$$\beta'(1)=-\frac{1}{4} \left(\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\gamma
   _1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+2 \pi  \log (2)\right)$$
$$\beta''(1)=\frac{1}{4} \left(\gamma _2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\gamma
   _2\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)+4 \left(\gamma _1\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\gamma
   _1\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\right) \log (2)+4 \pi  \log ^2(2)\right)$$

If I am not wrong
$$I_2=\frac{1}{18} \left(-3 \log ^2(2)+3 \log (2) \log (3)+\sqrt{3} \pi  \left(\log
   \left(\frac{128}{27}\right)+8 \log (\pi )-12 \log \left(\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)\right)\right)$$